# Contantes não funcionam no JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Bom dia Pessoal, não sei se serei claro, mas estou com uma dificuldade aqui. Preciso setar o caminho da URL no meu JavaScript.

```
define('URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/sistema/');
$html      = str_replace('#URL#'    ,URL            ,$html);
```

Defini essa constante, e a mesma funciona no HTML e PHP perfeitamente. Mas no Javascript fica como se fosse uma String, já tentei diversas maneiras, e acredito que seja fácil de resolver, mas estou tendo muita dificuldade. Vejam o Javascript.

```
var url = '" . URL . "';

function criaAJAX() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// Codigo para IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else
    {// Codigo para IE6, IE5
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}
```

Agradeço.

Comment: Testa `var url = '<?= URL?>';`

Comment: Não funcionou amigo.